# Where are the binaries located?

Tags: ios, xcode, external, livecode

I have an xcode project for livecode iOS external. When I build and run, it says successful but where I can locate the dylib and lcext files? I saw binaries folder but looks like it is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold down the "control" key while clicking on your target product, you'll be able to show it's location in the Finder.

Like this:

[image: Show In Finder]

Comment: Thanks Michael but looks like that file is corrupted on my project, is there a way to add it back?

Comment: what do you mean by "corrupted"?  you mean that target (the .app) is red and missing?

Comment: Yes, it is red and it can't be open in finder. Probably it was accidentally deleted. Is there a way to add it back?

Only items under Products are in red. The others are okay.

Comment: if you build the Release / Distribution version (i.e. "Build for Archiving" will do this with the default schemes), you'll see the target turn black.  Open that folder up and then one level up you'll see the "Debug" folder with it's build apps as well.

Comment: I don't think this is a LiveCode-specific answer.

Comment: no, it's not a LiveCode-specific answer @Mark ... it's more of an Xcode specific answer.

Comment: Right. And I'm not sure that the binaries for LC are found under "Products". I always just look in the actual build folder in the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds odd but are you getting any errors after Xcode says it was successful? If so then you need to check the .ios file includes all your frameworks. There is a shell script that re-links the external.